# Georeferencing via GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal, linux

Plugin GDAL didn't work on my qgis 2.18.17. I'm working on linux mint 19

Installed version : Version 3.1.9 (dans /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgeorefplugin.so)
How i can change the version of GDAL?

Comment: Georeferencing plugin not depends on GDAL library. It depends on [GSL library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/). Please provide more details about your problem: error message and reproducible steps.

Comment: @DmitryBaryshnikov, do you mean some other plugin than the one named "Georeferencer GDAL" that is a core plugin and the version number seems to be the same 3.1.9 in my QGIS 3.4.4?

Comment: @SaifeddineFarjallah sorry, I little mistaken - it depends on both libraries. But again what is the error message? Also you can check dependencies using `ldd /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgeorefplugin.so`.